# What do you all recommend for backing up git workspaces/clones?

Tags: git, backup, git-clone

I need a backup that included uncommitted modifications because my developers don't like to commit often.

Comment: You need better developers...

Answer (score 5):

Just `rsync` the clone ( including working directory) to another location frequently.

Comment: Wouldn't this require tons of disk space?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) for this: just work from inside your dropbox.

**Caveat:** Does not backup when offline.

Comment: isn't this a windows app?  We are a linux shop.

Comment: No, it's cross platform. There is a [Linux version](http://www.dropbox.com/downloading?os=lnx).

Answer (score 0):

I think ebneter's answer has some merit.

The hardest part about using git is unlearning bad habits from all the other SCMs. It sounds like your developers need some proper workflow training. This will also require you to take some time to understand why they are resisting checking the code in.

For example, it may be the case that they just are against committing broken code. With git, this is not a problem as long as they don't push the code to a shared branch public repository. You also then need to train them on how to use rebase to squash the local commits together when they're ready to publish it.

Secondly, since the local commits are not backed-up, you still have a data loss problem. (Of course, this assumes the remainder of their files are not backed up, but out of the scope of this question.)

One solution would be to let your developers push their experimental branches to the public repository, then if anything happens, the commits are safe. Be sure to use a branch naming convention for the public repo, so there will not be any branch name conflicts.

Comment: All of us are very new to git, so the developers are struggling with being able to do diffs on multiple commits to see what they have changed before they push. So, they wait until they are ready to deliver their changes and then they can run git diff and see the uncommitted changes in the index in one command.  They are also very nervous about using git rebase -i.